# How to access images from different folder in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in React JS and I want to import images in a src/views/Landingpage/index.js! These images are inside of the src/assert/image/ folder and I do not know how to access the images?

The structure folder is:

[image: The structure folder is:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

1. You can import the image in the component where you want to use it by giving it's path:

```
import photo from 'assets/image/photo.jpeg';
```

And then use it in your image tag:

```
<image src={photo} alt="alt-text"/>
```

2. You can have your assets inside the public folder and then pass the path like:

```
<image src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/image/photo.png}` alt="alt-text"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Put your assets inside public directory for get access to your assets without import statement. For example, you can create folder Images inside public directory: `'public/Images'`
Then you can access to this using code below:

```
<img src="./Images/*ImageName*" alt="404"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import the images just like you would import a component.

for example, in your index.js

`import imageName from "../../assets/image/imagename.jpg"`

then in the `src` of image put the `imageName`

`<img src={imageName}/>`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, try this: `import imageName from '../../assets/image/imageName.jpg'`